# DateFormatter gives weird timezone for very old dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

For a client of mine I'm working with really old dates like for example:

- 0572-06-17
- 1000-06-17

When I convert the string to a date it has a weird timezone.
Example:

```
extension String {
    func yearMonthDayDate() -> Date? {
        return DateFormatter.yearMonthDayFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}

extension DateFormatter {
    static let yearMonthDayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateFormatter.locale = .current
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}

extension Date {
    func zonedDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        dateFormatter.locale = .current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
print("1000-06-17".yearMonthDayDate()!.zonedDate())
1000-06-17T00:00:00+00:17
```

Like you can see the timezone is +00:17.
Why is this weird timezone showing up?

Comment: By any chance, is your current timezone Belgium?

Comment: Sorry you are right I forgot the correct line. So yes I'm converting it to a dateFormat that the java backend wants. Yes I'm living in Belgium why?

Comment: Wow I actually got it right. Posting an answer now.

Comment: I'm curious :-D thank you for your help already!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, each local area kept their own [local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) by observing the times of sun sets and sun rises. This meant that the local time at each town/city not be a nice whole number offset from Greenwich, like +17 minutes for example. This wasn't that big of a problem until people invented trains, which had schedules. At around the 19th century, countries around the world [standardised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_time) their local times, and that is why we have nice whole number offsets like +1 hour (most of the time).

So in the year 1000, your timezone, `Europe/Brussels` was really 17 minutes ahead of Greenwich as far as the history we know. This bit of history got recorded in the IANA `tz` database, which is what `TimeZone` queries. That is why you got `+00:17`.

Interestingly, when I ask the `TimeZone` how many seconds it is from GMT at around the 1000s, it says 0:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 86400 * 365 * -1000)
// this is 0
TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Brussels")!.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
```

It might have rounded the actual number of seconds down. Java can tell you the actual answer though:

```
// prints +00:17:30
System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels")
    .getRules().getOffset(LocalDate.of(1000, 1, 1).atStartOfDay()));
```

Comment: I didn't knew :-) thank you so much for this information. Pretty cool

Comment: @user1007522 now you should know why I was able to guess that it is Belgium :)

Comment: I was really surprised that you said Belgium :-D